# When should i build 'dist' folder and when i should not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack

I know dist folder is used for production, distribution and what it should contain.

What i want to know is, when is the best time to use it? in what kind of work environment/project requirement i should use dist folder? like Heroku, what are the other platforms where i can deploy an app without dist and the platforms where i can't deploy without it (if there is any)?

I'm new to this, if someone can clearify the process would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The dist folder is for production website it's not necessary to have it. It will contain for example your image, css, script, vendor folder ready for production (minified and concatenated).
You can check on google for this. Type "how to deploy a production React app to Heroku" for example.

Comment: Then when do we need dist folder? I know how to deploy without it to Heroku, but I want to know what is the purpose of it.

Comment: Typically the dist folder will contain an image/ , css/, script/, vendor/ folder ready for production (minified and concatenated)

Comment: A dist folder is required when your source, e.g. what you check into Git, is not suitable for serving in production. In the context of a web app, the source needs to be compiled, transpiled, optimised etc. So the dist folder holds the result of _building your code_. Your web server then serves optimised assets from the dist folder, rather than the originals. If you don't need to serve optimised/transpiled assets, then you don't need a dist folder.

Comment: @JedRichards thanks for the explanation. If I have a express server and want to build dist, how do I connect it every time I build.

Comment: Once you've generated your dist folder you need to tell Express to serve static files from it https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html